# Spring Transactions Flow

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

Need to understand if all the three flows of lockData are in one transaction. Can I see the row lock added by Class **C1** on table employee when the flow comes back to Class **A1**?

Flow currently is: An instance of `A1` calls an instance of `B1` which in turn calls an instance of `C1`

```
class A1 {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void lockData(){ 
        B1 classBObj = ctx.getBean("B1");
        boolean locked = classBObj.lockData();      
        //Check if lock on employee table is still there.
    }   
}

class B1 {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void lockData(){ 
        C1 classCObj = ctx.getBean("C1");
        classCObj.lockData();   
        return true;
    }
}

class C1 {  
    public void lockData(){ 
        executeQuery("select * from employee where emp_id=1 for update");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the instance of `A1` used is a spring-bean and injected through the spring bean context then yes, a call to `a1.lockData()` (and all its nested calls) will be executed in one transaction.

For completeness sake, I would suggest annotating `C1:lockData` with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`.

Comment: A1 is a JSF managed-bean . B1 and C1 are spring  beans. I am able to see the row lock in db level when the flow goes back from C1 to B1. The issue is that I am unable to see the row lock in db level when the flow goes back to A1.

Comment: The `A1` bean must be created through the Spring-bean context. Otherwise, it will not be wrapped in an appropiate proxy to create the transaction. I updated my answer to iniclude this information.